# IE 11 Developer Tools (open) decreases load times 3x's

Tags: javascript

Was running tests on an internal webpage using IE, to check load times, and noticed the page loads roughly 3x's faster while having the developer tools open.  I can reproduce this 100% of the time, and as soon as I close developer tools the website significantly slows down.  If I had to guess it would be javascript related but outside that we're not sure.

Chrome and Firefox are lightning fast in comparison but IE is our corporate standard.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Check your code for calls to console; when devtools isn't open, attempts to write to console fail.  You might be getting a lot of exceptions when you don't have dev tools open.  Exceptions are costly.

Comment: `IE is our corporate standard.`  Didn't the corporate's learn anything from IE6?.. :)

Comment: Appreciate the prompt response.  We checked the consol.log before posting here, and verified there was no debugger code either.   @Keith - I'm with you buddy, I'd much rather default to something else.

Comment: If it is the console log, and I've a feeling it might be. you can check for  `window.console`, and patch it with a dummy one.

Comment: Upgrading IE 11 from 11.0.41 to 11.0.47 solved the issue.  Thanks for all the responses!